# Can't install NME from source

Tags: haxe, nme

```
$ haxelib list
format: [3.0.2]
hxcpp: [3.0.2]
nme: [dev:C:\Users\NME/]
nmedev: [dev:C:\Users\nmedev/]
svg: [1.0.7]
swf: [1.0.0]

$ nme
Error: Library nme version dev is not installed
```

Anyone run into this? Everything is up to date.

Answer (score 3):

https://code.google.com/p/haxe/issues/detail?id=1853

"Editing the file manually and removing the trailing slash resolves the problem"

Edit the .dev file inside the lib that's giving you the problem. 
IE C:\Program Files (x86)\HaxeFoundation\haxe\lib\nme.dev
was C:\some\path\NME/
edit to C:\some\path\NME